# SDL missing x86_64 architecture

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard, sdl

I'm trying to get the SDL example code for XCode working on my Snow Leopard machine, however every time I attempt to build I receive this error: 
"ld: warning: in /Users/me/Dropbox/Programming/Obj C/Space/SDL.framework/SDL, missing required architecture x86_64 in file"
Originally it was to "/Library/Frameworks/..." but I have copied the entire SDL.framework into my project and linked to it, however the error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem with the pre-built binaries from the SDL homepage. You need to compile SDL yourself to get it to work.

The simplest way to do this is to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). You can install Homebrew with a [single command](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew) from the Terminal. After that, run

```
brew install sdl
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: I have done so and got the SDL folder in /usr/local/Cellar, however it is set up differently than the Frameworks I'm used to, what do I need to include into the XCode project? Or should I replace the Frameworks in /Library/Frameworks with the headers in /Cellar/sdl/.../include?

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest SDL.Framework from here:

- http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php

It has a folder called SDL.framework inside, replace your existing framework with the one from the download.

You will likely need to do a clean, then build to get it to work.

Not related to your question exactly, but I also needed to replace these frameworks for the same reason:

- http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/
- http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/